# install specific version of postgresql on mac using brew

Tags: macos, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to install postgresql 9.2 on OS X 10.9.3 and getting the following error. How can I solve it?

```
$ brew install postgresql92
==> Downloading http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.2.6/postgresql-9.2.6.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql92-9.2.6.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file src/pl/plpython/Makefile
patching file contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql92/9.2.6 --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql92/9.2.6/share/postgresql92 --docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql92/9.2.6/share
checking for POSIX signal interface... yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for tclsh... /usr/bin/tclsh
checking for tclConfig.sh... no
configure: error: file 'tclConfig.sh' is required for Tcl

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:182:in `dump': undefined local variable or method `f' for #<BuildError:0x007ff6029ef250> (NameError)
  from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:158:in `rescue in <main>'
  from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:66:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can "solve" the Tcl error adding the flag `--no-tcl` to the brew command:

```
$ brew install postgres --no-tcl
```

Hope it helps.